# Remove dots from column names

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with several columns and I want to remove the dots on the column name. The data is as follows:

```
structure(list(JulDay = c(260.0208435, 260.0416565, 260.0625, 
260.0833435, 260.1041565, 260.125), i.46.j.8.k.1 = c(17.99964905, 
18.5903511, 22.93223381, 25.75687981, 25.78559113, 25.8169651
), i.47.j.8.k.1 = c(18.36571884, 21.15985107, 24.80698013, 25.75730324, 
25.78366089, 25.65381622), i.48.j.8.k.1 = c(18.45543289, 22.02331543, 
24.99463654, 25.5712738, 25.64232635, 25.66119385), i.46.j.8.k.2 = c(17.99798965, 
18.60897827, 22.95389748, 25.75719261, 25.78653336, 25.81692505
), i.47.j.8.k.2 = c(18.36762619, 21.17233467, 24.82248497, 25.75767899, 
25.7840023, 25.64115906), i.48.j.8.k.2 = c(18.45938683, 22.04619026, 
24.9859066, 25.56440544, 25.63998032, 25.66089439), i.46.j.8.k.3 = c(17.99430084, 
17.92090797, 19.67384911, 21.70389938, 23.67287827, 24.04380417
), i.47.j.8.k.3 = c(18.36631203, 19.82550049, 21.42166328, 23.76496887, 
24.87460899, 25.41026688), i.48.j.8.k.3 = c(18.44684792, 20.60981369, 
22.68632317, 24.1877079, 25.12503052, 24.99880028), i.46.j.8.k.4 = c(17.98368073, 
17.92047691, 18.11532974, 18.67082596, 20.23210907, 21.7181263
), i.47.j.8.k.4 = c(18.33089066, 18.41581535, 18.53464127, 19.18972206, 
20.14752388, 20.11002922), i.48.j.8.k.4 = c(18.21522522, 18.52231598, 
19.21397209, 19.58755302, 20.11982536, 21.28104591)), .Names = c("JulDay", 
"i.46.j.8.k.1", "i.47.j.8.k.1", "i.48.j.8.k.1", "i.46.j.8.k.2", 
"i.47.j.8.k.2", "i.48.j.8.k.2", "i.46.j.8.k.3", "i.47.j.8.k.3", 
"i.48.j.8.k.3", "i.46.j.8.k.4", "i.47.j.8.k.4", "i.48.j.8.k.4"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can anyone let me know how to remove the dots from column names ?

> I want something like i46j8k1, i47j8k1, i48j8k1.

For this simple data set I could manually replace the name, but I need to do this for several data sets.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

One straightforward way is to use `gsub` to remove the periods from the column names:

```
> names(mydf)
 [1] "JulDay"       "i.46.j.8.k.1" "i.47.j.8.k.1" "i.48.j.8.k.1" "i.46.j.8.k.2"
 [6] "i.47.j.8.k.2" "i.48.j.8.k.2" "i.46.j.8.k.3" "i.47.j.8.k.3" "i.48.j.8.k.3"
[11] "i.46.j.8.k.4" "i.47.j.8.k.4" "i.48.j.8.k.4"
> names(mydf) <- gsub("\\.", "", names(mydf))
> names(mydf)
 [1] "JulDay"  "i46j8k1" "i47j8k1" "i48j8k1" "i46j8k2" "i47j8k2" "i48j8k2" "i46j8k3"
 [9] "i47j8k3" "i48j8k3" "i46j8k4" "i47j8k4" "i48j8k4"
```

Comment: I was playing around with gsub but couldn't figure it out. Thanks so much Ananda.

Answer (score 11):

```
library(janitor)

mydf %>%
  clean_names()
```

The `clean_names` function in `janitor` package will remove any characters that are not lower-case letters, underscores, or numbers. It may convert the periods to underscores though, so if your goal is to get rid of that character completely the gsub solution will work best.