# Using cbind on XTS object changes the dash (-) character in previous column names to a dot (.)

Tags: r, xts, cbind

I have some R code that creates an XTS object, and then performs various cbind operations in the lifetime of that object. Some of my columns have names such as "adx-1". That is fine until another cbind() operation is performed. At that point, any columns with the "-" character are changes to a ".". So "adx-1" becomes "adx.1".

To reproduce:

```
x = xts(order.by=as.Date(c("2014-01-01","2014-01-02")))
x = cbind(x,c(1,2))
x
           ..2
2014-01-01   1
2014-01-02   2

colnames(x) = c("adx-1")
x
           adx-1
2014-01-01     1
2014-01-02     2

x = cbind(x,c(1,2))
x
           adx.1 ..2
2014-01-01     1   1
2014-01-02     2   2
```

It doesn't just do this with numbers either. It changes "test-text" to "test.text" as well. Multiple dashes are changed too. "test-text-two" is changed to "test.text.two".

Can someone please explain why this happens and, if possible, how to stop it from happening?

I can of course change my naming schemes, but it would be preferred if I didn't have to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merge.xts` converts the column names into *syntactic names*, which cannot contain `-`.  According to `?Quotes`:

> ```
>  Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period
>  ('.') and the underscore.  They must not start with a digit nor
>  underscore, nor with a period followed by a digit.
> ```

There is currently no way to alter this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the behavior is precisely the one Joshua Ulrich highlighted. It's common across many data types in `R`: you need "valid" names. [Here is a great discussion of this "issue".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195718/variable-name-restrictions-in-r)
For data frames, you can pass the option `check.names = FALSE` as a workaround, but this is not implemented for `xts` object. This said, there are plenty of other workarounds available to you.
For instance, you could simply rename the columns of interest after very `cbind`.  Using your code, simply add:
`colnames(x)[1] <- c("adx-1")`
to force back your desired column name.
Alternatively, you could consider [this `gsub` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041935/remove-dots-from-column-names) if you wanted something potentially more systematic.